# Какой модуль из библиотеки PyQt5 нужно передавать классу приложения?

Tags: python, pyqt5, классы, gui, наследование

Какой родительский класс нужно передавать классу при построении приложения с *PyQt5*?

В моём случае есть класс `SkeletonOfWindow`, если его наследовать от класса `QWidget`, то класс будет распознавать все модули и функции из `QWidget`.

Но в интернете множество разных примеров, в которых передают не только `QWidget`, но и другие модули!

Какой класс более универсален для наследования моему классу?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


class SkeletonOfWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SkeletonOfWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @S.Nick, а что с ней не так? : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все зависит от того какие задачи вы будите выполнять.

1. Класс QWidget - это базовый класс всех объектов пользовательского интерфейса.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QDialog
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class SkeletonOfWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
       
        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello World")
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(label)        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SkeletonOfWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

2. Класс QMainWindow предоставляет главное окно приложения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QDialog
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class SkeletonOfWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
       
        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello World")
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(label)        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SkeletonOfWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

3. Класс QDialog - это базовый класс диалоговых окон.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QDialog
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class SkeletonOfWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
       
        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello World")
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(label)        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SkeletonOfWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Да, большое спасибо.

Comment: Вот, спасибо. Не знал, как это сделать. Думал, что нажатие стрелочки "Вверх" около ответа и есть это